# How do you vertically align an empty div inside a full height div?

Tags: css, html

Big picture: I'm trying to make a bar graph made up of discrete units. Each unit will be a div. The bar will grow from bottom to top.

Details: I have a container div that holds all of the unit divs, or blocks. The container has a vertical-align of bottom to do this.

This is what it should look like: https://jsfiddle.net/hpf4h/1/

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>

#container {
    height: 100px;
    width: 10px;
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: #00f;
    
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.block {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    margin: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
    background-color: #0f0;
}
```

That works fine, but I need the container to have a height of 100%. Which makes this happen: https://jsfiddle.net/7n7ZH/1/

I'd prefer to find a way to do this with CSS, preferably not too hacky. I'm already using jQuery for the behavior in my project, so I could use that as a last resort.

Edit: Also, all parent tags also have a height of 100%, including HTML and body.

Comment: the way 100% height works (say like if ur doing a layout as a template/master page) you need the parent elements e.g. body/html also to be 100%. That may not work for you. This looks like a meter of some sort it may be easier to just set the height of the container etc using jQuery or something based on its parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make #container's container element `display:table` like this : https://jsfiddle.net/7n7ZH/2/

```css
html, body { height: 100%; margin:0; }

body { display:table; }

#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 10px;
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: #00f;
    
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.block {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    margin: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
    background-color: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

When you use `display:table-cell` the browser looks for ancestor elements being `display:table-row`, `display:table-row-group` and `display:table`. If it can't find them, it creates pseudo elements to stand in for them. That's what's happening here.

So when you say `display:table-cell; height:100%`, that's 100% of the created pseudo element that is `display:table`. But that pseudo element is only as high as its content, and there's no way in CSS to say "make the pseudo-element have height that's 100% the height of its parent instead".

But it is possible to have a real element be `display:table` and set its height to 100%, in which case the browser will use that and not create the `display:table` pseudo element.

Answer (score 1):

Applying `display:table-cell;` and `height` at the same time rarely gives the results you'd expect.  I see that you're trying to use `vertical-align` which is probably why you added the `table-cell`.  Try css positioning instead:

Remove `display:table-cell;` and `vertical-align` from your container.

Add `height:100%;` to both the `body` and `html` elements so your container has room to grow.

Set the container to `position:relative;` which will make it the origin of all positioned children rather than the document root (body tag). This will allow you to move your container around without screwing up the child positions.

Add a wrapper around your blocks (you could use ul, li for this rather than divs).

Position the block container as `position:absolute; bottom:0;`

Here's the code...

```
#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 10px;
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: #00f;
    
    position:relative;
}
.blockContainer
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}
.block {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    margin: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
    background-color: #0f0;
}

body { height:100% }
html { height: 100%}#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 10px;
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: #00f;
    
    position:relative;
}
.blockContainer
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}
.block {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    margin: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
    background-color: #0f0;
}

body { height:100% }
html { height: 100%}
```

...and here's the fiddle...

https://jsfiddle.net/kPEnL/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to provide assistance with doing it in the way you have started, but taking your original big picture of trying to make a vertical progressbar, here's an alternative which uses the [progressbar in Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#progress).  In its existing form, it doesn't do vertical progress bars, but [this modification](http://minddust.github.io/bootstrap-progressbar/#v-bottom) does.

I originally suggested using stacked bars, but this doesn't work with the vertical implementation.  Instead, I've got a solution which uses CSS gradients to draw the blocks in, but still uses the normal bootstrap progress bar.

```
.progress.discrete {
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, 
        black 0%, green 5%, green 95%, black 100%);
    background-size: 100% 10%;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

/* Bar is used to cover up the blocks, so make it look like a background */
.progress.discrete .bar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f5f5f5, #f9f9f9);
}
```

I assumed you wanted your blocks to be a percentage of the bar height rather than an absolute size - this means I can't apply the gradient to the bar.  Instead, it can be applied to the background, and the bar used to cover it up (i.e. set width of the bar to 100-progress%).  I've also included an example which uses a fixed block size applied to the bar if that's what you wanted.

http://jsfiddle.net/BHTXZ/3/

It needs a little tidying up, but does the trick.